# Java converting parameterized .xml screen file to an ingestable .xml format

Tags: java, xml, dom

Heading converting parameterized .xml screen file to an ingestible .xml format

Am getting back in the driver’s seat on java and xml; the environment is JDK 1.6 and need to do the following:

Read in .xml screen dumps in the format something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<d: param = “root _tags” type = “string” value ="test Value">
    <d: param = “child1 tag” type = “string” value = “data 2” > 
    </d: param > 
    <d: param = “child2 tag” type = “string” value = “data 2” > 
    </d: param >
</d: param>
```

Convert the param(s) to actual tabs in interCap format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rootTag type “string” value ="test Value">
    <child1Tag type = “string” value = “data 2” > </child1Tag > 
    <child2Tag type = “string” value = “data 2” > </child1Tag>
</rootTag >
```

Write to file the new tags and types to a file for a data dictionary:

```
rootTag string
child1Tag string
child2Tag string
```

Remove the types and write out a new .xml so I can bring them into my database in this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rootTag>test Value
    <child1Tag data="1" > </child1Tag> 
    <child2Tag data="2" > </child2Tag>
</rootTag >
```

I am rusty on Java and very rusty on xml parsing (2004) and am under the gun.

Comment: Neither your input nor the desired output xml is well-formed. You will have difficulties with these formats since no xml parser will work well with malformed documents.

Answer (score 0):

You need several things here:

1. If the xml's have a unified format (they all have the same structure) you can get an XSD or write one ([XSD Tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_intro.asp)) and then you can use a framework like [XmlBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/) to generate java objects from the schema and work with them. That would be the easiest way.
2. The other option is to use the java [DOM API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/intro/dom.html). The API is a bit ugly but once you get used to it it's not that hard. Problem is that you need to take care of every xml structure manually.
3. One more option is using [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp), i never tried it with java but you can find resources easily.
4. As for writing to regular files, look [here](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/java-write-to-file.shtml) , it is quite easy.